# Concatenate with new observations- DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I'm trying to concatenate with new observations. I got the answer that I think it's right but still get the system came back to me saying "ValueError
Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects" Can anyone tell me why there's value error while I think I got the right result?

Here is the question:

Assume the data frame Employee is as below:

```
      Department      Title  Year Education Sex
Name                                           
Bob           IT    analyst     1  Bachelor   M
Sam        Trade  associate     3       PHD   M
Peter         HR         VP     8    Master   M
Jake          IT    analyst     2    Master   M
```

and another data frame new_observations is:

```
         Department Education Sex      Title  Year
Mary             IT             F         VP   9.0
Amy               ?       PHD   F  associate   5.0
Jennifer      Trade    Master   F  associate   NaN
John             HR    Master   M    analyst   2.0
Judy             HR  Bachelor   F    analyst   2.0
```

Update Employee with these new observations.

Here is my code:

```
    import pandas as pd
    Employee =pd.DataFrame({"Name":["Bob","Sam","Peter","Jake"],
                    "Education":["Bachelor","PHD","Master","Master"],
                   "Sex":["M","M","M","M"],
                    "Year":[1,3,8,2],
                   "Department":["IT","Trade","HR","IT"],
              "Title":["analyst", "associate", "VP", "analyst"]})

    Employee=Employee.set_index('Name')

    new_observations = pd.DataFrame({
               "Name": ["Mary","Amy","Jennifer","John","Judy"],
               "Department":["IT","?","Trade","HR","HR"],
               "Education":["","PHD","Master","Master","Bachelor"],
               "Sex":["F","F","F","M","F"],
               "Title":["VP","associate","associate","analyst","analyst"],
               "Year":[9.0,5.0,"NaN",2.0,2.0]},
               columns= 
               ["Name","Department","Education","Sex","Title","Year"])

    new_observations=new_observations.set_index('Name')

    Employee = Employee.append(new_observations,sort=False)
```

Here is my result:

[code result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oArSf.png)

I also tried

```
Employee = pd.concat([Employee, new_observations], axis = 1, sort=False)
```

Comment: I receive no error and result looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pd.concat` on `axis=0`, which is default, so you don't need to include axis:

```
pd.concat([Employee, new_observations], sort=False)
```

Output:

```
         Education Sex Year Department      Title
Name                                             
Bob       Bachelor   M    1         IT    analyst
Sam            PHD   M    3      Trade  associate
Peter       Master   M    8         HR         VP
Jake        Master   M    2         IT    analyst
Mary                 F    9         IT         VP
Amy            PHD   F    5          ?  associate
Jennifer    Master   F  NaN      Trade  associate
John        Master   M    2         HR    analyst
Judy      Bachelor   F    2         HR    analyst
```